# ValueError on ImageField when trying to delete image or creating new user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, imagefield, django-uploads

I have put an ImageField on my Django model, and with the pre-existent profiles it works (the image upload), but I can't delete the image from the admin panel and I can't create a new user.
The thrown error is:

> ValueError at /admin/custom_user/customuser/1/
>   The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/custom_user/customuser/1/
>   Django Version: 1.8
>   Exception Type: ValueError
>   Exception Value:
>   The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
>   Exception Location: /home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py in _require_file, line 46
>   Python Executable:  /home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.6
>   Python Path:    
>   ['/home/stefano/projects/blog-project',
>    '/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/lib/python2.7',
>    '/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>    '/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Thu, 24 Mar 2016 13:12:38 +0000

This is the model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    second_name  = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    email        = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=datetime.now())
    avatar       = models.ImageField('profile picture', upload_to='images/avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'second_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.avatar)
        new_image = resizeimage.resize_width(pil_image_obj, 300)

        new_image_io = BytesIO()
        new_image.save(new_image_io, format='JPEG')

        temp_name = self.avatar.name
        self.avatar.delete(save=False)

        self.avatar.save(
            temp_name,
            content=ContentFile(new_image_io.getvalue()),
            save=False
        )

        super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried to put null=True and blank=True on the model, but the error is still there. I've tried to put required=False on "**init**" method in forms.py

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'E-Mail',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'First name',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    second_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Second name',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    avatar = forms.ImageField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'label': 'Profile pic'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'second_name', 'avatar')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['avatar'].required = False

    def clean_email_address(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if self.user and self.user.email == email:
            return email
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'That email address already exists.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Still there.

What can be done?

EDIT: Here's the complete traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/custom_user/customuser/1/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'custom_user',
 'django_markdown',
 'parsley')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1519.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1467.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1078.         obj.save()
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/custom_user/models.py" in save
  66.       pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.avatar)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in open
  2261.         fp.seek(0)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py" in <lambda>
  20.     seek = property(lambda self: self.file.seek)
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in _get_file
  49.         self._require_file()
File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in _require_file
  46.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/custom_user/customuser/1/
Exception Value: The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a condition asking if `self.avatar` before opening the avatar image could work because if there is not an avatar there is not reason to delete it, from my point of view. Something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.avatar:
        pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.avatar)
        new_image = resizeimage.resize_width(pil_image_obj, 300)

        new_image_io = BytesIO()
        new_image.save(new_image_io, format='JPEG')

        temp_name = self.avatar.name
        self.avatar.delete(save=False)

        self.avatar.save(
            temp_name,
            content=ContentFile(new_image_io.getvalue()),
            save=False
        )

    super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I hope this can help you to find the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! Good to know that. Thanks to let me know

Answer (score 0):

When you creating an instance there is no avatar file stored on disk. So you try to open not existed file.

I see you want here to delete old file after update?

So you don't need to override `save` method. What you should do is to use `pre_save`, `post_save` and `post_delete` methods.

On `pre_save` you store current avatar, and after update on `post_save` you should check new instance's file path with old one. If it is different then delete it by `os.remove`

On `post_delete` just remove file.

[Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/)